# Can jQuery Datatables in a search results web part return more than 50 documents?

Tags: web-part, jquery, search-results, display-template, datatable

I've hit a wall on figuring out how to remedy this issue. Im currently developing a search center page with jQuery datatables and control and item display templates. The search results webpart is configured to use a result source, and when configuring the result source, the test query returns all docs in the library. I have the max setting of 50 set to the number of items per page that should be returned. I know the issue stems from the control template, as when i removed it, it returned all of the documents, when i set it back to use the control template, it only returned 50 docs. below is the code from the control template

```
`<html xmlns:mso="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:msdt="uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882">  
<head> 
    <title>Tax Template Datatable Control</title> 

    <!--[if gte mso 9]><xml> 
    <mso:CustomDocumentProperties> 
        <mso:TemplateHidden msdt:dt="string">0</mso:TemplateHidden> 
        <mso:MasterPageDescription msdt:dt="string">Display a Accordion Control</mso:MasterPageDescription> 
        <mso:ContentTypeId msdt:dt="string">0x0101002039C03B61C64EC4A04F5361F385106601</mso:ContentTypeId> 
        <mso:TargetControlType msdt:dt="string">;#SearchResults;#Content Web Parts;#</mso:TargetControlType> 
        <mso:HtmlDesignAssociated msdt:dt="string">1</mso:HtmlDesignAssociated> 
        <mso:HtmlDesignConversionSucceeded msdt:dt="string">True</mso:HtmlDesignConversionSucceeded> 
        <mso:CrawlerXSLFile msdt:dt="string"></mso:CrawlerXSLFile> 
        <mso:HtmlDesignPreviewUrl msdt:dt="string"></mso:HtmlDesignPreviewUrl> 
        <mso:HtmlDesignStatusAndPreview msdt:dt="string">https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx, Conversion successful.</mso:HtmlDesignStatusAndPreview>
    </mso:CustomDocumentProperties> 
    </xml><![endif]--> 
</head> 

<body>         
    <script>
    </script> 

    <div> 
        <!--#_
        if (!$isNull(ctx.ClientControl) && !$isNull(ctx.ClientControl.shouldRenderControl) && !ctx.ClientControl.shouldRenderControl()){return "";} 
        ctx.ListDataJSONGroupsKey = "ResultTables"; 
        ctx["CurrentItems"] = ctx.ListData.ResultTables[0].ResultRows; 
        AddPostRenderCallback(ctx, function() {
                $(document).ready(function(){
                    $('#datatable').DataTable({

                    });
                });
            });
        _#-->
```

Document Name
            Last Modified Time

```
</thead> 
<tbody> 
    <div id="Groups" class="ms-srch-result-groups"> _#= ctx.RenderGroups(ctx) =#_</div>
</tbody>
```

`

Is there some limitation that datatables have when using a sharepoint search results webpart?

PS: the code snippet feature on this site cut off the end of the code, which is just some plain ole HTML

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by using an unsupported workaround. Just insert the code below into a Script editor (key in script tags too) and edit the newMaxItems variable to a size that is appropriate. Note: if you insert larger sizes in the newMaxItems variable, it will affect performance.
`

```
var CC = window.CC || {};
CC.CORE = CC.CORE || {};

CC.CORE.IncreaseSearchResultsMax = (function () {
    "use strict";

    var $ocreate = null;
    var newMaxItems = 100;
    var oldMaxItems = 50; // web part must be set to show this many items

    // on application initialization 
    // steal the global create variable and 
    // intercept calls to create UI widgets.
    Sys.Application.add_init(function() {
        $ocreate = $create;
        $create = updateResultCountCreate;
    });

    // listen to UI widget calls for CBS & DP
    var updateResultCountCreate = function (a,b){
        var ps = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);  
        if(a === Srch.ContentBySearch && b.numberOfItems === oldMaxItems) { 
            b.numberOfItems = newMaxItems;
        }
        if(a === Srch.DataProvider && b.resultsPerPage === oldMaxItems) {
            b.resultsPerPage = newMaxItems;
        }
        $ocreate.apply(this,ps);  // apply the original $create method that we stole
    };
    return true;
})();
```

`